# Проблема с инициализацией переменных c++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В другом месте этот же самый код работал.

```
void registration ()
{
  DB_connect c;
  c.createConnection();

  QSqlQuery query_mysql(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql"));
  QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
  QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
  QSqlRecord rec  = query_mysql.record();
}
```

Выдаёт ошибки:

```
/db_connect.cpp:61: error: variable 'QSqlQuery query_mysql' has initializer but incomplete type
   QSqlQuery query_mysql(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql"));
                                       ^
/db_connect.cpp:62: error: incomplete type 'QTextCodec' used in nested name specifier
   QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
                       ^
/db_connect.cpp:63: error: incomplete type 'QTextCodec' used in nested name specifier
   QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
   ^
/db_connect.cpp:64: error: variable 'QSqlRecord rec' has initializer but incomplete type
   QSqlRecord rec  = query_mysql.record();
              ^
```

Comment: Ошибка вида 'incomplete type' явно говорит о том, что не подключен соответствующий заголовочный файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё компилируется нормально, скорее всего проблема в какой-то другой части вашего кода. Вы должны знать, что компилятор невсегда может точно определить где ошибка, он лишь подсказывает, а человек думает и анализирует.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}

void registration ()
{
      //DB_connect c;
      //c.createConnection();

      QSqlQuery query_mysql(QSqlDatabase::database("dbsql"));
      QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
      QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(codec);
      QSqlRecord rec  = query_mysql.record();
}
```